# Image pixel color picker with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, colors, pixel, picker

First of all this is not a simple "color picker". So there's a picture (size and content does not matter) and i want to pick the color of some pixels (and then use these color to generate a HTML or Canvas based halftone "image").

[image: how it work]

For example: There is a 240x240 image. I want to pick the color of the following coordinates: x80y80, x80y160, x160y80, x160y160. How can i get them with jQuery/javascript (excluding jQuery UI)? Is it necessary to use canvas element?

I would appreciate if somebody could help me on this mission.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would help you mate - http://www.project-sierra.de/ImageColorPicker/example/

Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

You can draw an img image into a canvas element, and than use it's canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData to get the pixel's information

Comment: There might be another, I just don't know it ;)

Comment: And this will probably not be supported by "older" browsers. Traditional image manipulation is done by GD or imagemagic.

Comment: i've to do this at client side so i have to choose canvas.